# Alerts on Custom Views

Tags: alert, document-library

I've been searching everywhere for this, and it appears to have been an easily achievable task in WSS3, but doesn't seem available at all in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

I'm just trying to setup an alert for a view of a document library. I have created 4 views, one for each segment of data that I have available, but the only alert I seem to be able to setup is one to alert on any changes for the entire library...

Apparently, it used to be possible to just select the view you wanted to be alerted on, but now, this is nowhere to be found.

Can anyone confirm whether this is even possible now? It should be a simple piece of functionality, and I wouldn't expect to have to code anything..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129478/mail-sent-with-workflow-takes-a-long-time-office-365-e3

Smart Alert Pro 

www.spmarketplace.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alerts are at the library level, and were with previous versions as well.  While you cannot tie an alert explicitly to a specific view, there is nothing stopping you from creating a simple workflow that notifies people when the criteria is met within the views.

Comment: Thanks, created a workflow to send the email based on the same criteria of the views, worked a treat.

Answer (score 9):

You CAN setup Alerts based on a view in WSS3/MOSS2007 onwards

See ["Setting up Alerts on a View of a List"](http://sharepointalert.info/2009/09/alert-me-tricks-fo-power-users/)

You won't see every view and only the Gods seem to know exactly why you can see some views and not others.

> 1) It must have a where clause.  All
>   Items views don't show up in the list
>   of views, and it's pointless to use an
>   All Items view because it doesn't
>   filter.
>
> 2) It must be a public view, it cannot
>   be a personal view.
>
> 3) It cannot involve content approval.

[See : Which views can be used when Creating an Alert ?](http://blog.blumenthalit.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=95)

Comment: Workflow is not Content Approval. Workflow can exist without content approval and Content approval without workflow.

Comment: just bumped into this. seems that we cannot use ootb fields in the filters either, as they immediately remove the view from the alert options

Answer (score 1):

We found yet another quirk that should be added to the list. The three requirements mentioned were all met. But still our view did not appear. We continued experimenting and found out that as soon as we added a Modified or Created = [Today]-21 criterium then the view dropped off the list of available views for setting an alert.

Comment: It seems that regardless of how creative you get to solve one of Microsoft's hurdles, they have already out thought you and placed another and higher hurdle right behind it.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use the 'alert me', only those views which have a filter set on them show up. Try to make a dummy filter on the views and see if you are able to use 'alert me' on them.