# Mail sent with workflow takes a long time (Office 365 - E3)

Tags: workflow, office-365, email

I have made a workflow that sends an email when an item is added.

The workflow does some tests and is completed in less than 1 minute. But the mail which is generated in that workflow takes hours before it is received.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

For example yesterday evening workflow completed at 16:58 and I received the mail at 18:52.

Thanks in advance!

WKR

Grim

Comment: We've been dealing with this issue ourselves.  We've found no solution.  Calls to Microsoft prove to be useless.  Fortunately, as long as the emails go out, it's not an issue as they're not on a time crunch.